# change "libpython2.7.a" version to 2.7.6 from 2.7.5 to install opencv 2.4.9

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install opencv on 'ubuntu 16.04 amd64'.

I got an error at 89% compilation due to python version.
In my cmake this is the problem.

```
   -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.0") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.5", but required is exact version "2.7.6" (found /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a)
```

What I have tried:
I did dpkg -s on all my packages.
except libpython-dev every other package is 2.7.6, I uninstalled libpython-dev and installed a 2.7.6 version of it from https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpython-dev.

I got broken packages error and had to revert back.

How to install new libpython2.7.a  "2.7.6" version?

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`? 
On Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (on my machine at least), it installs the 2.7.6 version.